# Custom products in Drupal or OSCommerce?

Tags: php, drupal, oscommerce

I've looked high and low. I think I'm not searching for the right stuff.

I want to know of a module, or plugin for either drupal or oscommerce that will allow you to "build your own products". I.e. A customer can go on the site, and say he wants PC A, with X amount of RAM, and Z sized harddrive etc.

1. Is there a plugin or module for either oscommerce or drupal out there that does this?
2. If not, any tips on how to go about assigning relationships to nodes in Drupal?
3. If not, any tips on how to accomplish this with OSCommerce?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a couple minutes of research, I've found a few Drupal modules you might pound together to get what you want. I am not particularly familiar with Ubercart's depths, this is just what *my* initial approach would be.

[Ubercart](http://drupal.org/project/ubercart), [UC Custom Price](http://drupal.org/project/uc_custom_price), [UC Node Checkout](http://drupal.org/project/uc_node_checkout), and [CCK](http://drupal.org/project/cck) (for nodereference).

Ubercart is the primary e-commerce solution for Drupal. UC Node Checkout allows you to add a node to a shopping cart when it is created. Node References allow users to reference existing products when they create their custom product node. And lastly, UC Custom Price should allow you to dynamically set the custom product's price by extracting price information from the referenced component products.

Answer (score 1):

i don't think there is something like this for Drupal. for OSCommerce, there seem to be some options:

- [Holbi osCommerce Product Customization Module (PC Configurator)](http://www.holbillp.com/modules-for-oscommerce/product/item/oscommerce-product-customization-module-pc-configurator/)
- [I.T. Web Experts Custom Computer/Product Creator](http://www.itwebexperts.com/custom-product-builder-package-combo-computer-customizer.php)
- [and possibly more](http://www.google.com/search?q=OSCommerce+product+%2Bconfigurator)

not free, though.

Comment: This is also very useful. Found it very hard choosing who is right. BOth of u are actually!

Answer (score 1):

I'm tracking this very issue, and leaving breadcrumbs here:
http://www.ubercart.org/forum/support/15925/correct_method_dynamically_generated_download_product_ubercart_22#comment-51097